# how to use pragrammable chat of twilio in c#

Tags: c#, twilio

can enyone help me out to undersatnd this Here's [a link](https://www.twilio.com/chat)! how to use in c# 
i want to know how to use it 
how to use pragrammable chat of twilio in c#

Comment: Did you go thru the documentation of API and SDK of chat?

Comment: yes but i don't get idea how to start for making demo of it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var client = new TwilioIpMessagingClient(accountSid, authToken);
Message message = client.CreateMessage(serviceSid, channelSid, memberSid, body);
Console.WriteLine(message);
```

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest/messages#action-create

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

There is a full [tutorial for using Twilio Programmable Chat from C# right here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/chat-csharp-mvc).

You might also find that the [Chat fundamentals documentation](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/chat-fundamentals) will help. The key is that you need to run a server which you can use to generate an [access token for your users](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/create-tokens) so that they can access the Chat service. Once you have done that, you can build the rest of the application in the front end. You can also [perform actions from C# using the REST API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/rest).